# How to enable Youtube API to my javascript

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I found this code in here, this code lets you know what is the total percentage does the user watch in youtube embeded video, I was just wondering why it does not work in me. I'm new with youtube API so please help.

```
// Html Code

<iframe id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_16Ii_6AvZk?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
        <p id="display"></p>

// Javascript Code

var player, timer, timeSpent = [], display = document.getElementById('display');

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player( 'player', {
        events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }
    });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 1) { // Started playing
        if(!timeSpent.length){
            for(var i=0, l=parseInt(player.getDuration()); i<l; i++) timeSpent.push(false);
        }
        timer = setInterval(record,100);
    } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

function record(){
    timeSpent[ parseInt(player.getCurrentTime()) ] = true;
    showPercentage();
}

function showPercentage(){
    var percent = 0;
    for(var i=0, l=timeSpent.length; i<l; i++){
        if(timeSpent[i]) percent++;
    }
    percent = Math.round(percent / timeSpent.length * 100);
    display.innerHTML = percent + "%";
}
```

Comment: Did you include the youtube iframe api js library to your page?

Comment: Ok thanks I will do it Patrick Evans

Comment: It would be nice to mention where you got your code from, and what API documentation you followed. Also, if @PatrickEvans 's suggestion helped, maybe add an answer with the solution? :)